# How to access cross region s3 bucket by lambda using CDK Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cdk

I have created lambda in region A and a S3 bucket in region B , trying to access bucket from lambda boto-3 client but getting an error(access denied).Please suggest some solution for this in python CDK. Will I need to create any specific policy for it.

Comment: Could you please share some code? E.g. how does the Lambda execution role looks like?

Comment: `Access Denied` suggests that the problem is related to permissions rather than the fact that it is cross-region. How is the IAM Role associated with the Lambda function being given permission to access the bucket in Region B? (These are all in the same AWS Account, right?)

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly pass the region name of the bucket if it is not in the same region as the lambda (because AWS have region specific endpoints for S3 which needs to be explicitly queried when working with s3 api).

Initialize your boto3 S3 client as:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='region_name where bucket is')
```

see this for full reference of boto3 client:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client

---------Edited------------
you also need the following policy attached to (or inline in) the role of your lambda:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you need to list and delete the objects too, then you need to have the following policy instead, attached to (or inline in) the role of the lambda:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmt1",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmt2",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: tried this but getting same error ! do I need any specific policy statement?

Comment: Hello @shubham,
Thank you for your question, could you share the policy statement of your lambda function? I can point out exactly what you need. :)